# CSRF token exchange from server to AngularJS client

Tags: java, angularjs, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm going crazy trying to figure out how to implement a CSRF protection for my Web app. I've read tons of pages but still cannot decide on the solution in my particular context.

So, first my Web app is written in Angular, deployed statically on an Apache server. It calls some services on my server, Java type, deployed in a war on an application server. Both of them are deployed on the same domain. After authentication the usual session cookie (secure+HttpOnly) is set in the response.

Now, I would like to implement a CSRF protection based on either a synchronizer token or a double submit cookie pattern (but from what I saw the first is a better solution as I can handle a state on server side).

Most of the solutions I saw are proposing to generate the token server side and to store it in a cookie so it can be accessed on client side. The constraint for this to work, and I would that it is a big one, is that the cookie cannot be HttpOnly, as Javascript would not be able to access it. Moreover I have the feeling that sharing the token in a non fully protected cookie wouldn't be a good idea. But it seems to be the recommended solution from AngularJS ...

So, if I discard this solution what am I left with?
Putting the token not in a cookie but rather in the response header? Is it secure?
Exposing a service to fetch the token? Seems practical but not sure if it is a good idea?
Expose a servlet to build a Javascript to provide the token, like in OWASP Guard?
Anything else?

EDIT: It seems that Spring is going for the injection of the token name and value in the HTTP response as a solution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. CSRF token should generated once per user session.
2. It should be stored in server side session (HttpSession in case of Java)
3. Client should store the token as a hidden parameter not in the browser's cookie.
4. Server should validate the presence of the CSRF token for each request and compare with the token stored in session.

More details : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Yes, all of that is clear. What I miss is how to transfer the cookie generated on server side to the client in a secure and clean way

Comment: Java EE applications pass the token as a request attribute back to the client. In case of AngularJS clients, I assume you can pass the token using JSON

Comment: You mean, as part of the login response for instance?